# Each role has its own accessible page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I create a project where admin and user can log in. I have JSP pages, only the admin can enter there, because access is restricted to the user. The user can go to certain pages.
I have two pages "allStudents.jsp" - only admin can go there.
And on this page "allStudentsUser.jsp" - only the user can enter.
So this is how to write the code in the controller correctly so that Tomkat read my "allStudentsUser.jsp" page.

Student Controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudentsUser",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsUser");
        return mv;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1234")).roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1234")).roles("USER")
                .and();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/allStudentsUser**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/allStudents**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addStudent/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/editStudent/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/deleteStudent/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/allStudents")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

AllStudents.jsp (for Admin)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Все студенты</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="it">
                <h3>Список всех студентов</h3>
                ${message}

                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>

                            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                            <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>${student.name}</td>
                                <td>${student.surname}</td>

                                <td><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" /></td>

                                <td>
                                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                        </a>
                                    </sec:authorize>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                                        </a>
                                    </sec:authorize>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

AllStudentsUser.jsp (For User)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Все студенты</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="it">
                <h3>Список всех студентов</h3>
                ${message}

                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>

                            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                            <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>${student.name}</td>
                                <td>${student.surname}</td>

                                <td><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" /></td>


                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Student Controller (add Secured)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

     @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudentsAdmin",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsUser");
        return mv;
    }



    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudentsUser",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsUser");
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: There is no reall question here. Please ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend to use `@Secured("ADMIN")` or `@Secured("USER")`.

if you want use it, add to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` at SecurityConfig.java.

example for your code:

```java
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        // ...
    }
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudentsUser",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUsers() {
        // ...
    }
```

guide link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-method

Comment: Bro i add new code in my question. Can you look right there wrote or not

Comment: Yes, i can look... why ask??